# I am trying to learn to implement a responsive/mobile friendly navigation

Tags: css, user-interface, navigation, responsive

I am looking for recommended books, which cover coding responsive navigations.

Thus far, I am considering this book.

[CSS book cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyXX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great book on responsive design. In fact, it was written by the guy who "created" responsive design. It's on Amazon, but it's a little pricey at $30, and there are only 5 left in stock. Here is the link:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/098444257X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098444257X)

FreeCodeCamp has a great video on this in their YouTube channel. Here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srvUrASNj0s&t=3731s

Also, you are most likely new to Stack Overflow (Welcome!) but this question is sort of off topic. There isn't really a question about your actual code. If you have a question seeking advice, I recommend using r/askprogramming on Reddit or somewhere on Quora. Hope this helps!